# React Native -how to clean use effect hook

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react native and currently trying to make an app with `firebase v9` for practice. I'm kinda stuck with the hook issue, as it says:

> [Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.]

This is the **Login Component:**

```js
const LoginScreen = ( {navigation}) => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [storeKey, setStoreKey] = useState([]);
    const [userName, setName] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (authUser) => {
        if(authUser){
            AfterLogin();
        }
    });
    return unsubscribe;
}, []);

    const signInUser =  () => {
        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then(async (re) => {
            //setIsSignedIn(true);
            AfterLogin();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        })
}

const AfterLogin = () => {
    if(!storeKey || !userName || !image){
        getData(setStoreKey, setName, setIsLoading, setImage);
    }
    navigation.replace('Drawer', {
        storeKey: storeKey,
        userName: userName,
        image: image,
    });
}
```

And this is the **getData Function:**

```js
const getData = async(setStoreKey, setName, setIsLoading, setImage) => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    if(user !== null){
        const email = user.email;
    
        const UserInfo = await getDoc(doc(db, 'users', email));
        if(UserInfo.exists()){
            setStoreKey(UserInfo.data().storeKey)
            setName(UserInfo.data().name);
            setIsLoading(false)
            setImage(UserInfo.data().postImage)
        
        }
        else{
            console.log('None')
        }
        return
    
    }
}
```

I guess the problem is happening in the `useEffect` in Login, but I don't know how to solve this :S

EDIT: I think the problem is from getData function. When I comment out getData function in AfterLogin, it works fine without error :S
but I don't know how it causes error.
Is it because it's async function?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (authUser) => {
      if(authUser){
        AfterLogin();
      }
    });
  return () => {
    unsubscribe();
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: thanks for the comment! i tried it, but still getting the warning message :S

Comment: @maz32 Okay I get it just remove the AfterLogin from signin function it will handle by authState change no need call AfterLogin there

Comment: oh that makes sense. I removed AfterLogin from signing function, but still getting an error. I think getData function in AfterLogin is the problem, as it's working fine without error when I remove getData function :S